# Bootstrap-select control populates but doesn't display as dropdown

Tags: javascript, asp.net, bootstrap-select, bootstrap-selectpicker

I have a `bootstrap-select` control declared in my page (for an ASP.NET web application), like so:

```
<div class="row mb-2">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <label class="form-label" for="ddlCategories">Choose A Category...<strong>(required)</strong></label>
        <select class="form-control selectpicker" id="ddlCategories" title="Select..."></select>
    </div>
</div>
```

On page load, I call the following Javascript function to load a list of categories via an AJAX call into the control:

```
function loadCategories() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "../handlers/getcategorylist.ashx",
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: null,
        success: function (response) {
            $('#ddlCategories').empty();
            $('#ddlCategories').append('<option value="0" selected>Please choose...</option>');
            for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++)
                $('#ddlCategories').append('<option value=' + response[i].ID + '>' + response[i].Name + '</option>');
            $('#ddlCategories').selectpicker('refresh');
        },
        error: function (request, status, error) {
            $('#toastDataError').toast('show');
            $('#btnFinish').prop('disabled', true);
        }                
    });  
}
```

The AJAX call functions properly, and the data is getting loaded into the control.  However, the `bootstrap-select` control doesn't display as a dropdown.  The arrow is there on the right side, but the dropdown itself doesn't function.  If I remove the `selectpicker` class then it displays properly.
I have tried including the line `$('#ddlCategories').selectpicker();'` both before and after the call to the function that loads the control, but it doesn't seem to make any difference.

This isn't an error with loading the necessary Javascript or CSS libraries either, since I don't get any errors to this effect in the console, so I am stumped as to why `selectpicker` doesn't work.
Any ideas on why this?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reconstructing a minimal reproducible example it seems that it is working.

```js
function success(response) {
  $('#ddlCategories').empty();
  $('#ddlCategories').append('<option value="0" selected>Please choose...</option>');
  for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++)
    $('#ddlCategories').append('<option value=' + response[i].ID + '>' + response[i].Name + '</option>');
  $('#ddlCategories').selectpicker('refresh');
}

// fake ajax
setTimeout(function() {
  success([
    {ID: 1, Name: "cat"},
    {ID: 2, Name: "dog"},
    {ID: 3, Name: "dogger"},
  ]);
}, 500)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Fy6S3B9q64WdZWQUiU+q4/2Lc9npb8tCaSX9FK7E8HnRr0Jz8D6OP9dO5Vg3Q9ct" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.14/dist/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.14/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row mb-2 mt-2">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <label class="form-label" for="ddlCategories">Choose A Category...<strong>(required)</strong></label>
      <select class="form-control selectpicker" id="ddlCategories" title="Select..."></select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am using Bootstrap 5.1.3 and jQuery 3.6.0, and if I use your script link for bootstrap-select, I get an "Uncaught type error' for the bootstrap-select constructor.

Comment: They don't support bootstrap 5. See their docs. Regardless, consider moving to bootstrap 4.6 since you are using jquery anyway and also there aren't much differences between those versions.

Comment: There are features in Bootstrap 5+ that I like, including ```form-floating```.  I will have to think about the options on that.  Thank you for the feedback though.

Comment: That is also available in bs4 (although *might* be slightly different)